# How to separate a string represents a Set, to its elements (including inner sets!) -java

Tags: java, string, set

I need to be able to separate this kind  of string
for example:
{2,{3,4,5},{6,{4,7}},9} to all its elements:
2
{3,4,5}
{6,{4,7}}(Here recursively)
9
So I can create an object(by classes I coded) for each by its kind- a Set, A numeric
And by the way also to find out if this string is not a correct set
for example: {2,{3,4
I tried to use the split function of String but split("[,]")
doesn't help when you have inner sets
the result of {2,{3,4}} after I  delete the first { and last } is:
2
{3
4}

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: I hoped it will make the spaces i wanted to make at the Question so it would be clear  but it didn't. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack data structure.

Iterate over the string characters. Every time you see an opening bracket push it to a stack, every time you see a closing bracket pop from the stack, and every time the stack is empty again after a pop operation means you reached the end of your next element that you want to save.

For your example:

```
2 --> save
    Your elements now are: 2
{ --> push "{"
    Stack is now: "{"
3 --> next element is now {3
4 --> next element is now {3,4
5 --> next element is now {3,4,5
} --> pop "{"
    (Stack is now: "" empty! --> save element {3,4,5})
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}
{ --> push "{"
    Stack is now: "{"
6 --> save
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}, {6
{ --> push "{"
    Stack is now: "{{"
4 --> save
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}, {6,{4
7 --> save
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}, {6,{4,7
} --> pop "{"
    (Stack is now: "{")
} --> pop "{"
    (Stack is now: "" empty! --> save element {6,{4,7}})
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}, {6,{4,7}}
9 --> save
    Your elements now are: 2, {3,4,5}, {6,{4,7}}, 9
```